# Rerender as HTML - JSON databind not supporting HTML - displaying tags

Tags: html, knockout.js, data-binding

Working on an application that is using knockout data binding. I'm not versed in data binding or much front end stuff for that matter. I have JSON data being pulled in and binded. This is what it looks like after the bind:

```
<span data-bind="text: serviceName"><a href="tst.com">here</a></span>
```

and it displays the HTML tags on the page as shown:

> `<a href="tst.com">here</a>`

The application does have another aspect that uses data binding in a similar fashion and supports HTML. I'm guessing that this is some kind of attribute or function to force plain text?

My questions:

- what should I be looking for that would do this conversion?
- Is there a way to re-render as HTML via JS after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the html binding for that.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html

```
<span data-bind="html: serviceName"></span>
```

This will render the value of serviceName as html inside the span.